# I can't run boot time service in android app

Tags: android

I'm going to start service at boot time in android application. The code is written in the following way. Unfortunately, this code does not give the desired effect. Can someone tell me what wrong with this code? Many thanks.

manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service
        android:name=".BootTimeService">
        <!--android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" -->
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".BootTimeService"/>
                <!-- action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" / -->
                <!-- category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" / -->
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".RunBootTimeServiceReciver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <!--android:exported="true" -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <!--category android:name="android.intent.category."/-->
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BootTimeService class:

```
public class BootTimeService extends Service {
    //region constants
    private static final String TAG = BootTimeService.class.getSimpleName();
   //public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
    //endregion
    //************************

    public BootTimeService() {
    }

    //region override methods
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    // This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
    // platform.  On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
    // method will not be called.
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        //handleCommand(intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //handleCommand(intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStartCommand",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service creating");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is created",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        try {
//            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(SERVERPORT), 0);
//            server.createContext("IS2", new IS2Handler());
//            server.createContext("DSP", new DSPHandler());
//            server.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(0x5) ); // creates a     default executor
//            server.start();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");
        //server.stop(0x1);
    }
    //endregion
    //************************
}
```

RunBootTimeServiceReciver class:

```
public class RunBootTimeServiceReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//    public RunBootTimeServiceReciver() {
//    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Log.i("reciver", "Before start backgroud service");
        Toast.makeText(context, "BackGroundService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BootTimeService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need least 1 activity for this. This activity is doing anything but it should specified at your manifest file. Like this :

**EDIT**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.boottimeapplication"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.boottimeapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.example.boottimeapplication.BootTimeService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.boottimeapplication.RunBootTimeServiceReciver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.boottimeapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

**RunBootTimeServiceReciver**

```
package com.example.boottimeapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RunBootTimeServiceReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("reciver", "Before start backgroud service");
    Toast.makeText(context, "BackGroundService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BootTimeService.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
}
```

**BootTimeService**

```
package com.example.boottimeapplication;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootTimeService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = BootTimeService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service creating");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to do this without any activity. However, I test it(With an activity like you say), but I did not get any results.

Comment: I edited my post. Try that. If you have no activity, you can't start service at boot all I know.

Comment: In this site [link](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82) author maintains that launched the service at boot time. If you see the Presented code,You noticed that, There isn't any activity in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on a device with API level >= 13, you should read the following blog post by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware): http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html

Basically, it says that any broadcasts will be received only after the user had launched the app at least once.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I test my app with an activity. I add main activity to my app, run app on emulator, lunch it, then i restart emulator, but after boot up completed, no things was happen :(

Comment: I've created a new project,that from beginning there was an activity as main activity in it. I do The whole process that was said to run a service at system boot time,and test it, this time it works correctly. The only difference between the old and new app is that in the previous project main activity was not added to project at creation time. Why has this happened In your opinion?